# Google Cloud doesn't recognize subfolder as having more files?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Recently been trying to validate which paths do exist within a GCS bucket the following way.

```
return StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
      .list("my-bucket-name", Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(("folder-inside/yet-another-folder/")))
      .hasNextPage();
```

Take into account the following structure within the bucket.

```
- my-bucket-name
|-- folder-inside
   |-- yet-another-folder
      | -- file.txt
```

It wouldn't really mind that `yet-another-folder` is empty as long as it exists. Both cases should return true, `yet-another-folder` existing or `yet-another-folder` containing further files.

This is, however, returning `false` everytime for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list return a pageable result (default values: 1000 per page without ACL detail, else 200). If there is more results, the hasNextPage() is true, else, it's false.

In your case, you have only 1 file, it is return in your list call, and there isn't next page of result, thus the hasNextPage() is false.

It's better to test the size of the returned list. If 0, no file AND no directory exists. If 1, only the directory exists with no file.